# Python, Recursively Generate custom tags from nested dictionary

Tags: python, html, json, dictionary, recursion

I'm building a custom dynamic template tool which can be integrated into any templating framework, i.e pugs, jinja etc...
I wanted this demo to look like:

```
view! {
    div {
        p {
            span {}
            strong {}
        }
    }
}
```

So, from the custom json data made of Html tags, I wanted to generate the posted output but i'm having a little issue with the recursion where the inner children tags are not printed out, except the top parent's tag.

```
tree_data = {
    "tag": "html",
    "children": [
        {
            "tag": "head",
            "children": [
                {
                    "tag": "meta",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "tag": "title",
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "body",
            "children": [
                {
                    "tag": "ul0",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "tag": "div0",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "tag": "div1",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "tag": "div2",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "tag": "div3",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "tag": "ul1",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "tag": "li0",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "tag": "li1",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "tag": "li2",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "tag": "div4",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "tag": "h1-0",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "tag": "div-5",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "tag": "h2-0",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "tag": "div6",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "tag": "div7",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "tag": "h1-1",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "tag": "h1-2",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "tag": "h2-3",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "tag": "div-8",
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and the function used to generate the tags is:

```
def template_tags(d, c_tag=""): 
    d_tag = d['tag']
    tag_tree = f'{c_tag} {{ {d_tag} }}'
    for c in d['children']:
        if c is not None:     
            c_tag = c['tag']
            template_tags(c)
    return(tag_tree)

my_view = f"""
    view! {{
          {template_tags(tree_data)}       
        }}
    """  

print(my_view)
```

This is what i've gotten instead as a result. How can this code be readjusted to have an entire tree returned?

```
view! {
           html       
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you're using to generate this? In particular, what you've posted so far is not a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: You aren't using the return value of the recursive call `template_tags(c)` anywhere

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark, the code i'm using to generate the json data is an SQL query where  I made the output to be a JSON data.

Comment: @shriakhilc, where do i use it ?

Comment: @alexander -- Nevermind, I hadn't realized that the dictionary was Python code (I thought it was raw JSON). It looks like it's cut off at the top though -- could you fix that?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark, I just updated that, and the function is after the json declaration, maybe I need to split that too

Comment: You are returning `tag_tree` from the function, which is nothing but your assignment `tag_tree = f'{c_tag} {{ {d_tag} }}'`. In the recursion end, the last return value will be the first tag you met, that will be `html`. You have to append your result and return that, and assign it back as well. That is how recursion is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

In your function, you need to gather up all of the child nodes generated by your recursive call.  You also want to indent those before returning them.  That means it needs to return a list, which you will then coalesce later:

```
tree_data = {
    "tag": "html",
    "children": [
        {
            "tag": "head",
            "children": [
                {
                    "tag": "meta",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "tag": "title",
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "body",
            "children": [
                {
                    "tag": "ul0",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "tag": "div0",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "tag": "div1",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "tag": "div2",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "tag": "div3",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "tag": "ul1",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "tag": "li0",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "tag": "li1",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "tag": "li2",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "tag": "div4",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "tag": "h1-0",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "tag": "div-5",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "tag": "h2-0",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "tag": "div6",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "tag": "div7",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "tag": "h1-1",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "tag": "h1-2",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "tag": "h2-3",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "tag": "div-8",
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}


def template_tags(d, c_tag=""): 
    d_tag = d['tag']
    tag_tree = f'{c_tag} > {d_tag}'
    myset = [tag_tree]
    for c in d['children']:
        if c:
            c_tag = c['tag']
            res = template_tags(c)
            myset.extend(['    '+s for s in res])
    return myset

nl = '\n'
my_view = f"""
    view! {{
{nl.join(template_tags(tree_data))}       
        }}
    """  

print(my_view)
```

Output:

```
    view! {
> html
     > head
         > meta
         > title
     > body
         > ul0
             > div0
             > div1
             > div2
         > div3
             > ul1
                 > li0
                 > li1
                 > li2
             > div4
                 > h1-0
             > div-5
                 > h2-0
         > div6
             > div7
                 > h1-1
                 > h1-2
                 > h2-3
         > div-8       
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, so if I understand correctly, in order to return the value from the loop, I need to add it to a list, declared in the outer scope, right?

Comment: Well, think about the function's job.  Its job is to return something that has ITS tag, plus the tags of its immediate children.  Each of those children will take care of their own children, but a single instance had to return one "thing" that has itself and its children.  You could do this with strings instead of a list, but using a list seems to make more sense to me.